# OpenGL ES: flat shading without duplicating vertices?

Tags: opengl-es, shader

Is there a way in OpenGL ES to do flat shading without repeating each vertex for every triangle?

In regular OpenGL this is done with `glShadeModel` but in ES I write the shaders so its not that simple.

GLSL 1.3 or 1.4 (not sure) introduces the keyword `flat` which seem to enable this but unfortunately ES 2.0 doesn't have this yet.

Yet another way to do this uses `dFdx`,`dFdy` functions which, alas, are also missing in ES.

Answer (score 7):

No, flat-shading is not a feature of OpenGL ES 2.0, sorry.

Comment: What about OpenGL ES 3.0?